# Messed support for Intl.DateTimeFormat with Chinese Calendar

Tags: javascript, chinese-locale, ecmascript-intl

```js
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('zh-CN-u-ca-chinese', { dateStyle: 'full' }).format(1680537600000)
```

The above code outputs `0040闰0214 12:00 上午` in Firefox, `2023癸卯年闰二月十四星期二` in Chrome/node/deno, `2023癸卯年闰二月14星期二` in bun.

Why those outputs are so different? How can I produce a uniform output?

Comment: _“Why those outputs are so different?”_ — Because they are implementation-dependent. _“How can I produce a uniform output?”_ — By using some other internationalization library. Which of these outputs do you need? Is any of these outputs _wrong_? Why do you want a uniform output?

Comment: The output date is not wrong, but the way to write chinese calendars is wrong, such as we are using `癸卯年` but not `0040` to refer a year name (like `Friday` instead of `5`). I'll give up using `Intl` for generate date strings and rely on other libraries. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Your firefox distribution might be an older version of [icu4c](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-72-1)